# Bonus stocks / shares in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash

What is the right way to record bonus stocks / shares received?

I used Actions -> "Stock Split" menu and it created a bonus entry.

When I try "Reconcile" it shows the record on both sides (Funds In and Funds Out) in the reconciliation window and obviously when I try selecting both of them it shows "difference" thereby not reconciling.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your financial situation, and how exactly you received the shares. If I received bonus shares of stock from employment, I would consider this 'income'. You could create a separate Income Account for 'Bonus' if you prefer.

Then when you receive shares, you increase your stock asset from the Income category. Effectively you have increased your total assets from income.

A Stock Split actually does not increase your assets or income, it simply divides the number of shares by a factor, often two (2), but the total net worth of the stock is the same. In this case, a bonus has increased the net worth of your stocks.

Comment: didn't quite understand your comment "Fixed, thanks for the find!"? What did you fix?

Comment: Someone else commented on my answer: there was a typo/spelling error. I thanked him and fixed the problem. For some reason the SE software then removed his comment. (Or maybe s/he deleted it.) So now my comment is an orphan. Feel free to ignore it.